# Finding factors of polynomials without every power descending

Tags: polynomials, factoring

There is a way for finding factors of polynomials with the biggest power being n in $a^n$, and other powers descending from $n-1$ in $b^{n-1}$ to $0$ in for example $z_0$. And it is solved by finding $p$ and $q$, and putting every possible $p/q$. What if we don't have all the powers? My example could be $$4x^4 - 5x^2 +6x -8$$ 
Please give a solution so at least we don't have to try out every number, and it is reduced to a finite amount of numbers.

Comment: Are you referring to the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)? So, for instance, in your example you would want to check $\pm\frac14, \pm\frac12, \pm1, \pm 2, \pm 4$ and $\pm 8$? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. This is the theorem i was talking about. Will it work for polynomials without every descending power, like my given example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rational root theorem does work in examples like yours. Note that the $x^3$ term isn't *really* missing. It's just hidden away. Your polynomial is equal to
$$
4x^4 +0x^3-5x^2 + 6x-8
$$
and nothing in the rational root theorem says it stops working if some of the coefficients are $0$ (just that the first and last coefficients must be non-zero).